# Trying to implement an alarm in my shell program. C Signal handling

Tags: c, signals, alarm

I am building my own shell in C. I want to implement an builtin called alarm that takes in an integer argument for the number of seconds. The builtin just sends the user a message after i seconds (once) but the shell functionality should continue working in the meantime.

Heres what I have so far:

```
int seconds;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[], char* envp[]){
   ...
   signal(SIGALRM, alarmHandler);
   ...
}

void alarmHandler(int sig) {
    signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
    alarm(seconds);
    printf("%s\n", "message");
    signal(SIGALRM, alarmHandler);
}
void mainProgram(char* string, char* argument){
    ... //built ins that don't require forking
    pid_t processID = fork();

    if(processID==0){ //child
        if(strcmp(string, "alarm") == 0){
            seconds = atoi(argument);
            signal(SIGALRM, alarmHandler);
    }else{ // parent
        usleep(100000)
    }
```

Clearly that doesn't work. I'm kinda lost. I've been trying this for the past couple of hours and I'm unsure of what to do.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not an adequate problem description. Please describe the problems you are facing more specifically.

Comment: Well, with the code above, nothing happens. So if I type in alarm 4 it's as if I just typed in enter and the shell prints out the prompt

Comment: Why do you set up the alarm in the alarm handler? The handler doesn't get called unless the alarm is already set.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've got the wrong idea of what `signal` does...

The [`signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) system call can be used for setting up **handling** of signals. Generally speaking, use the [`kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) system call for **sending** signals.

OTOH, perhaps it's the difference between [BSD signal handling semantics](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bsd_signal.3.html) and [System V signal handling semantics](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysv_signal.3.html) that's contributing to the confusion. System V signal handling semantics can necessitate calling `signal` (again) within the signal handler function. Newer linux systems at least stick with the BSD signal handling semantics which are reliable and don't require `signal` to be called again unless you wanted to change the handler that gets invoked.

As a side note, once you get past using `signal` correctly, I'd recommend using `sigaction` instead. You can read the 'Portability' section of the `signal` manual page that I linked to learn more about why you should use `sigaction` instead of `signal`.

But onwards...

There are other system calls that can be used to send signals in addition to the `kill` system call. Like in your case you may want to use [`alarm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) or [`setitimer`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html).

Alternatively, if you wanted to implement something like what `alarm` does (without using `alarm` or `setitimer`), you could use a separate process (via a call to `fork` perhaps) that calls a sleep function followed by calling `kill` like this:

```
usleep(100000);
kill(pid, SIGALRM);
```

In this example then, `pid` would be the process ID of the process that you wanted to send the `SIGALRM` signal to (which is the signal that `alarm` sends).

Hope this helps answer your question.